# How to find a region which has maximum number of 1's in C?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d, traversal

I have a 500x500 2D matrix which contains values either 0 or 1.Is there any way to find out the highly concentrated region which contains value 1 or lets say a region with maximum no of 1's.I tried traversing the whole 2D matrix with a smaller (50x50 size array) but its taking a very long time. Is there is any other way which is more efficient and takes lesser execution time.I have to do this in C programming.

Comment: what have you done so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: You should use dynamic programming to reduce complexity of this problem.

Comment: I tried traversing the array with smaller sized array and keep track of no of 1's in that smaller array but since its a 500x500 sized array traversing the whole array is taking a whole lot of time so plz suggest any other method or way to do the above think in lesser time.

Comment: @REACHUS I thought of using dynamic programming but dont know how to approach this problem with dynamic programming and also how to implement dynamic programming in this situation.

Comment: On any other method for consuming less time: Go for a dynamically-typed language like Python.

Comment: Moreover in programming, you need to be specific about what exactly is "highly concentrated region".

Comment: It is not clear what you mean exactly with "region with maximum numbers of 1". Also, traversing a 500x500 array does not take a lot of time. Perhaps you could show us your slow code so we can see where the problems are.

Comment: @Pranav here by highly concentrated region I mean a region which contains maximum number of 1's and I have to do this in C programming only.

Comment: @Ohem I m traversing 50X50 sized array row-wise in 500x500 sized array for calculating number of 1's so I want to know is there any other way to do the same thing.

Comment: So you are really looking for the 50x50 subarray of your 500x500 array that contains most 1s?

Comment: @Peter here I assuming the size of array that I used for traversal is 50X50   it may be lesser or greater than that

Comment: @Eregrith  I havent asked you to do my homework I just want another way to solve this problem.And even I know that maximum number of 1's is 500x500 array but I want to find the maximum count in a subarray which is a size of 50x50

Comment: @Ohem yes exactly I want to find a 50x50 subarray which contains maximum number of 1s.

Answer (score 0):

To improve efficiency you can use parallel technique. You can use for it for example CUDA.

Also it is a good idea to use specific neighbour algorithm and compute the most dense space.

Comment: Can you give me any link from which I can use the above mentioned algorithm If you have. because I have to complete this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you state that you really want to find the 50×50 subarray that has most ones. A naive implementation could be to iterate over the array and then over each subarray to find the maximum sum:

```
void subarray(char array[500][500], int *x, int *y, int *pmax)
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    int max = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < 450; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 450; j++) {
            int n = 0;

            for (k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l < 50; l++) {
                    n += array[i + k][j + l];
                }
            }

            if (n > max) {
                max = n;
                *x = i;
                *y = j;
                *pmax = max;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will take long, because you have four nested loops. A better approach might be to introduce an auxiliary array that stores the number of ones up to and including the current point for every entry in the array. This information can be gathered incrementally from neighbouring elements.

If you want to calculate the number of ones in a rectangle with top left point `(x0, y0)` and with bottom right point `(x1, y1)`, you get:

```
n = count[y1][yy1] + count[y0][x0] - count[y0][x1] - count[y1][x0]
```

So:

```
void subarraye(char array[500][500], int *x, int *y, int *pmax)
{
    int count[500][500];
    int i, j;
    int max = -1;

    count[0][0] = array[0][0];

    for (i = 1; i < 450; i++) {
        count[i][0] = count[i - 1][0] + array[i][0];
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 450; i++) {
        count[0][i] = count[0][i - 1] + array[0][i];
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < 500; j++) {
            count[i][j] = count[i - 1][j] + count[i][j - 1]
                        - count[i - 1][j - 1] + array[i][j];
        }
    }       

    for (i = 0; i < 450; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 450; j++) {
            int n = count[i + 50][j + 50] + count[i][j]
                  - count[i][j + 50] - count[i + 50][j];

            if (n > max) {
                max = n;
                *x = i + 1;
                *y = j + 1;
                *pmax = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The indices are off by one, because the number of ones up to the exclusive bound `(x, y)` are stored in `(x - 1, y - 1)` and the top and left row of zero-area rectangles are omitted.